# My Live vlc video stream works on the emulator but not on a real device

Tags: android, vlc

Hi I'm new to Android studio, I'm having an issue where I'm trying to play a vlc live steam on my phone but I get a message after a few seconds saying "video cannot be played". The strange thing is that video live stream will play on the emulator in android studio. I will add my code below. I have added internet permissions to the manifest also. If anyone could help it would be great, thanks in advance

```
 //XML Code
 <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.pkinsellaweb.BabyMate.VideoScreen"
 >

<VideoView
android:id="@+id/videoView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

//Java Code
public class VideoScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_screen);

    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


    String vidAdd = "http://192.168.43.66:8160";
    Uri videoPath = Uri.parse(vidAdd);
    video.setVideoURI(videoPath);

    MediaController mediaController = new
            MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the device is connecting to the server?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. No, I'm not exactly sure my device is connected to the server. I assumed an active internet connection is all my device would need? How can I conform if my device is connected to the server? Sorry if that's a stupid question with an obvious answer but I'm new to Android.

Comment: I'm not a VLC expert. But since you can't rule out a network problem, that should be given due consideration. If VLC logs its connections, you can troubleshoot based on that. If not, tools like Wireshark and tcpdump can be used instead (on your server). More general network debugging may be necessary; it's a larger topic than I can go into here.